# Что означают составные операторы?

Tags: c++builder, c++

Что означает на С++?

> `*=
> +=
> ==`

Comment: Возьмите книжку и прочитайте. Минус Вам от меня.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подобные вопросы лучше всего прояснять в справочнике языка. Значение операторов таково:

- `x *= y` эквивалентно `x = x*y`,
- `x += y` эквивалентно `x = x+y`,
- `x == y` равно `true`, если `x` равно `y`.

Comment: Всё это пришло из C. `==` -- операция сравнения "равно", два символа для того, чтобы отличать её от операции присваивания ("не равно" -- `!=`. Операции `*=`, `+=` -- относятся к бинарным операциям, совмещённым с операцией присваивания. Их достаточно много.